# django select query--how do I make this?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

```
class Content(models.Model):
    .....stuff here

class Score(models.Model):
    content = models.OneToOneField(Content, primary_key=True)
    real_score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

This is my database schema.  As you can see, each Content has a score.
How do I do this:

Select all from Content where Content's Score is 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Content.objects.filter(score__real_score=1)`